# Why does GAE Java background have /_ah/background calls every few seconds

Tags: java, google-app-engine, background

I keep seeing logs to URL /_ah/background.  Is it because of the use of background threads?  Who is making these calls and who is answering them.  Any idea anyone?  Thanks!

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-devappserver2-experiment/source/browse/google/appengine/runtime/background.py